# Fix the "space-expansion" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two problems with the [space-expansion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-expansion) tag.

## (1) <strike>The tag info is factually incorrect.</strike> [now corrected, thanks!]

> Space expansion is a cosmological phenomenon wherein the proper distance between two spatial points for a given inertial reference frame increases from one moment of time to another. That is, space itself expands; the added distance is not due to relative motion of points or objects.

This is a common misconception, unfortunately propagated in many old answers on this site. The contents of the Universe are expanding, but there is not an objective sense in which *space itself* expands. Within the context of mainstream physics, "expansion of space" is not a physical phenomenon. It's just an artifact of common coordinate choices in cosmology.

This point has been discussed at length in many answers. See for example:

- [Space expansion is a description of the coordinates and not the physics.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/807720/180843)
- [There is no concept of "expanding space" in general relativity.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/505727/180843)
- [Expansion of space is not distinguishable from objects moving away.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/771021/180843)

I am aware that I can submit an edit to the tag info without posting a meta thread about it. I did, and the edit was rejected. There is also a deeper problem:

## (2) [space-expansion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-expansion) should be a synonym for [cosmic-expansion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmic-expansion), and not the reverse.

As a research cosmologist, I would never write "space expansion" or "expansion of space" in a paper. The standard terms for the expansion of the Universe are "cosmic expansion", "expansion of the Universe", or "Hubble expansion". This preference is borne out in the statistics.

##### "Cosmic expansion" appeared in the abstracts of [625 papers over the last decade](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/search/fq=%7B!type%3Daqp%20v%3D%24fq_database%7D&fq_database=(database%3Aastronomy%20OR%20database%3Aphysics)&q=%3Dabs%3A%22cosmic%20expansion%22%20year%3A2014-2024&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc&p_=0).

[image]

##### "Expansion of the Universe" appeared in the abstracts of [1747 papers over the last decade](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/search/fq=%7B!type%3Daqp%20v%3D%24fq_database%7D&fq_database=(database%3Aastronomy%20OR%20database%3Aphysics)&q=%3Dabs%3A%22expansion%20of%20the%20universe%22%20year%3A2014-2024&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc&p_=0).

[image]

##### "Hubble expansion" appeared in the abstracts of [300 papers over the last decade](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/search/fq=%7B!type%3Daqp%20v%3D%24fq_database%7D&fq_database=(database%3Aastronomy%20OR%20database%3Aphysics)&q=%3Dabs%3A%22Hubble%20expansion%22%20year%3A2014-2024&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc&p_=0).

[image]

##### "Space expansion" appeared in the abstracts of [131 papers over the last decade](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/search/fq=%7B!type%3Daqp%20v%3D%24fq_database%7D&fq_database=(database%3Aastronomy%20OR%20database%3Aphysics)&q=%3Dabs%3A%22space%20expansion%22%20year%3A2014-2024&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc&p_=0), *and most of them are not even related to cosmology*!

[image]

Just one paper from the most recent 10 is a cosmology paper:
[image]

##### "Expansion of space" appeared in the abstracts of [152 papers over the last decade](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/search/fq=%7B!type%3Daqp%20v%3D%24fq_database%7D&fq_database=(database%3Aastronomy%20OR%20database%3Aphysics)&q=%3Dabs%3A%22expansion%20of%20space%22%20year%3A2014-2024&sort=date%20desc%2C%20bibcode%20desc&p_=0), and a significant fraction of them are not related to cosmology.

[image]

Just four papers from the most recent 10 are using "expansion of space" in a cosmology sense:
[image]

Comment: Uh, I'm pretty sure you can propose these changes since you've got >2k rep. Is a meta post necessary for this then?

Comment: @KyleKanos As noted in the post, "*I am aware that I can submit an edit to the tag info without posting a meta thread about it. I did, and the edit was rejected.*" It seems the change is controversial enough to warrant a meta post... (Also, do you know how to propose swapping synonym with canonical tag?)

Comment: [This says it was approved](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/447110) & I don't see other tag wiki edits going back into Feb in the review.

Comment: @KyleKanos It was [last year](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/424174). I am happy that the new edit is approved! Still interested in the tag/synonym swap, which I am not sure it is possible to propose.